# AltBeacon Library is unstable when detecting iBeacons in both foreground and background

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I've fully followed the procedures in the [AltBeacon' reference app](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) and its tutorial to make iBeacon detection in both foreground and background for my app.

Actually, my app does detect the iBeacons. I will send a notification after detecting an iBeacon.

However, the ranging process may suddenly stop after several minutes, no matter my app is in foreground or background(especially when the device is locked).

Sometimes, it will restart the detection (i)after I re-turn on the Bluetooth in the device, (ii)after I restart the app. But sometimes it won't.

I implemented BootstrapNotifier and RangeNotifier in the custom application of my app. And below is some code snippet

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, RangeNotifier {
private static final String TAG = "MyApplication";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
private int notificationID = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1100l);

    Region region = new Region("MyRegion", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).setRangeNotifier(this);
    try {
        BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't start ranging");
    }
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {

}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

}

private void sendNotification(Beacon beacon) {
    String message = beacon.getId3().toString();

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Where")
            .setContentText(message).setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RDMainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Beacon", beacon);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID++, mBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
        sendNotification(beacon);
    }
}
```

My testing device is Nexus 7(2013 Mobile version) with Android4.4.4

Is there anyone has any idea on this issue? Any helps will be appreciated.

Updated: Here is the logcat after my last detection in foreground

```
02-06 20:25:28.795  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
02-06 20:25:28.815  19482-19482/com.myapp W/CycledLeScanner﹕ Internal Android exception scanning for beacons
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.stopScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:771)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter$GattCallbackWrapper.stopLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.java:1819)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.java:1722)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2.finishScan(CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2.java:67)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.finishScanCycle(CycledLeScanner.java:249)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scheduleScanCycleStop(CycledLeScanner.java:234)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner$1.run(CycledLeScanner.java:230)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 20:25:29.936  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
02-06 20:25:29.936  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
02-06 20:25:29.956  19482-19493/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=8
02-06 20:25:31.087  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
02-06 20:25:31.097  19482-19482/com.myapp W/CycledLeScanner﹕ Internal Android exception scanning for beacons
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.stopScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:771)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter$GattCallbackWrapper.stopLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.java:1819)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.java:1722)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2.finishScan(CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2.java:67)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.finishScanCycle(CycledLeScanner.java:249)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scheduleScanCycleStop(CycledLeScanner.java:234)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner$1.run(CycledLeScanner.java:230)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 20:25:32.218  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
02-06 20:25:32.218  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
02-06 20:25:32.228  19482-19493/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=9
02-06 20:25:33.360  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
02-06 20:25:33.370  19482-19482/com.myapp W/CycledLeScanner﹕ Internal Android exception scanning for beacons
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.stopScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:771)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter$GattCallbackWrapper.stopLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.java:1819)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.java:1722)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2.finishScan(CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2.java:67)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.finishScanCycle(CycledLeScanner.java:249)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scheduleScanCycleStop(CycledLeScanner.java:234)
            at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner$1.run(CycledLeScanner.java:230)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 20:25:34.521  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
02-06 20:25:34.521  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
02-06 20:25:34.551  19482-19493/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=133 clientIf=0
02-06 20:25:35.652  19482-19482/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
```

Comment: What is the device you're using? I was observing the same problem with 1-sec scans on Galaxy S3. It seems that the Bluetooth stack simply crashes. You might want to try increasing the scan periods, see if that helps.

Comment: Can you post a Logcat excerpt for a 5 second period following your last detection?  A foreground excerpt is probably most useful.

Comment: @davidgyoung Thanks for your advice. I have posted the logcat as you said. I did not notice this exception before. Any idea of this exception?

Comment: Can you see if you get the same exception when running the Locate app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate